# Scala compiler crash with stack overflow error

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala application with `scala version 2.11.8` and `sbt version 1.2.6`. I am running the following command in command line

```
sbt clean compile
```

and clean phase works exactly fine whereas the compile phase fails with a stackoverflow error. The error log is as follows

```
[error] ## Exception when compiling 353 sources to C:\Users\Projects\target\scala-2.11\classes
[error] null
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5367)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]
[error] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5367)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
```

Now the irony is that the same code compiles and run when I run `sbt clean compile` from Intellij Idea. 
Can anyone point out what is going wrong here ? Do I need to remove sbt and re-install in again ?
Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/contribute/bug-reporting-guide.html

Comment: This is off topic here. Report scala compiler bugs at https://github.com/scala/bug
Also, you should provide mvce to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dima I did not know whether it was a scala compiler bug or not. Also could you please let me know what mvce means ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar any compiler crash is a bug. MVCE means "minimal verifiable code example". You should show what the input to the compiler was that made it crash.

Comment: @Dima the code that I am working on is a client code and that too its a huge code base. I cannot replicate that or share any of its detail.

Comment: well ... that's too bad. I am not sure what sort of response you expect then.

Comment: How do you run `sbt clean compile` from intellij. Do you mean the terminal in intellij or the sbt shell in intellij?